# Custom Alert Box Shows up Incorrectly

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

I am using slayeroffice's custom alert box, slayeroffice(period)com/code/custom_alert/. (Can't post more than two links) On my browser it  shows up like this. The alert box is the blue one in the middle of the screen.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1TEz.png

On my local it shows up like this, I highlighted the alert box. I wish i could image link this.
It works on the same version version of browser but one of them is on local.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xehV.png

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code integrated with slayeroffice's code.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Test1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test1" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    Namespace="System.Web.UI" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>

 <script type="text/javascript">

 function showPopUp(){
  setTimeout(function() {alert("Warning");}, 5000);
 }

  function delayer(){
  showPopUp();
  }


  // constants to define the title of the alert and button text.
var ALERT_TITLE = "Oops!";
var ALERT_BUTTON_TEXT = "Ok";

// over-ride the alert method only if this a newer browser.
// Older browser will see standard alerts
if(document.getElementById) {
    window.alert = function(txt) {
        createCustomAlert(txt); //overrides alert method
    }
}

function createCustomAlert(txt) {
    // shortcut reference to the document object
    d = document;

    // if the modalContainer object already exists in the DOM, bail out.
    if(d.getElementById("modalContainer")) return;

    // create the modalContainer div as a child of the BODY element
    mObj = d.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(d.createElement("div"));
    mObj.id = "modalContainer";
     // make sure its as tall as it needs to be to overlay all the content on the page
    mObj.style.height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight + "px";

    // create the DIV that will be the alert 
    alertObj = mObj.appendChild(d.createElement("div"));
    alertObj.id = "alertBox";
    // MSIE doesnt treat position:fixed correctly, so this compensates for positioning the alert
    if(false) alertObj.style.top = document.documentElement.scrollTop + "px";
    // center the alert box
    alertObj.style.left = (d.documentElement.scrollWidth - alertObj.offsetWidth)/2 + "px";

    // create an H1 element as the title bar
    h1 = alertObj.appendChild(d.createElement("h1"));
    h1.appendChild(d.createTextNode(ALERT_TITLE));

    // create a paragraph element to contain the txt argument
    msg = alertObj.appendChild(d.createElement("p"));
    msg.innerHTML = txt;

    // create an anchor element to use as the confirmation button.
    btn = alertObj.appendChild(d.createElement("a"));
    btn.id = "closeBtn";
    btn.appendChild(d.createTextNode(ALERT_BUTTON_TEXT));
    btn.href = "#";
    // set up the onclick event to remove the alert when the anchor is clicked
    btn.onclick = function() { removeCustomAlert();return false; }


}
// removes the custom alert from the DOM
function removeCustomAlert() {
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].removeChild(document.getElementById("modalContainer"));
}
 </script>
    <form id="form1" runat="server"> 
    <div>
        &nbsp;</div>
        &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="delayer();return false;" />&nbsp;
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Anything that detects a "newer browser" by checking for the existence of the "getElementById" method needs to be retired to a computing museum.

Comment: It looks like you're missing css to style the popup. That aside, though, I would go with a more modern solution. This one seems a bit outdated.

Comment: Hopefully you do not need window.alert() to be blocking.

Comment: Outdated indeed... from the screenshot: "This has been tested and verified to work in MSIE6, Firefox 1.0, Safari and Opera 7.1+"

Comment: @Pointy  Do you guys have any suggestions? I'm using visual studios 2005. I need to make a customizable alert box without using JQuery ui.

Comment: @EkoostikMartin Hi, I have a slight problem. Here's the image url. http://i.stack.imgur.com/kwv2s.png. How do you give the alertbox a separate window? It's plastered to the same window.

Comment: Well the thing is that this solution doesn't really mimic `alert()` completely. The real `alert()` blocks almost all other browser activity in the page. All this does is cover up the page elements with a "shroud" to block mouse/touch interaction. (On old IE browsers in fact it might have problems with `<select>` elements "poking through"!) If you want simple modal dialogs, there are many newer solutions available.

Comment: @Pointy So it's not possible to make it a separate window?

Comment: @user2561912 you can't make something that acts just like the real `alert()` window, no.  You can make things that are modal, but they won't block JavaScript execution the way `alert()` does.

Comment: @Pointy I know that, but slayeroffice's example shows up as a separate window. I don't really need it to block javascript execution. What do you need to add to make it a separate window?

Comment: It is not really a separate window. The code you posted just adds a container element to hold the alert message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the styles:

```
<style type="text/css">

#modalContainer {
    background-color:transparent;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:10000;
    background-image:url(tp.png); /* required by MSIE to prevent actions on lower z-index elements */
}

#alertBox {
    position:relative;
    width:300px;
    min-height:100px;
    margin-top:50px;
    border:2px solid #000;
    background-color:#F2F5F6;
    background-image:url(alert.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:20px 30px;
}

#modalContainer > #alertBox {
    position:fixed;
}

#alertBox h1 {
    margin:0;
    font:bold 0.9em verdana,arial;
    background-color:#78919B;
    color:#FFF;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    padding:2px 0 2px 5px;
}

#alertBox p {
    font:0.7em verdana,arial;
    height:50px;
    padding-left:5px;
    margin-left:55px;
}

#alertBox #closeBtn {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    margin:5px auto;
    padding:3px;
    border:2px solid #000;
    width:70px;
    font:0.7em verdana,arial;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-align:center;
    color:#FFF;
    background-color:#78919B;
    text-decoration:none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you. I knew I was missing something.